# Define a string in qmake command line

Tags: g++, qmake

I need to pass a string as a definition to my source code which is a base64 encoded string (so may contain `/` and `"`). I'm using qmake and g++. I've tried so many combinations, but neither works:

```
qmake DEFINES+=SERIAL=\\\"f9a/z\\\"
qmake DEFINES+=SERIAL=\"f9a/z\"
qmake DEFINES+="SERIAL=\\"f9a/z\\\""
```

G++ should get the serial like this:

```
g++ -DSERIAL=\"f9a/z\"
```

Answer (score 3):

In bash:

```
qmake DEFINES+=SERIAL=\\\\\\\"\"f9a/z\\\\\\\"\"
```

In a scripting language:

```
"DEFINES+=SERIAL=\\\\\\\"" + str + "\\\\\\\""
```