# How to pass a QMAKE variable from the command line?

Tags: linux, qt, cross-compiling, qmake

I am to trying cross-compile pile Qt from a Linux terminal.  When I run qmake it applies the mkspecs qmake.conf in my context in such manner that the CROSS_COMPILE variable must be defined.  For example, there is a critical conf line that looks like this:

```
QMAKE_CXX               = $${CROSS_COMPILE}g++
```

Qmake returns an error though which clearly indicates $${CROSS_COMPILE} is not being resolved.  It is simply using "g++" instead of the whole value which ought to be there.

I've tried to invoke qmake and define the variable from a bash script like this:

```
qmake qt.pro "CROSS_COMPILE=${CROSS_COMPILE}"
```

And like this :

```
qmake qt.pro -- "CROSS_COMPILE=${CROSS_COMPILE}"
```

And a few other such stabs at it.  I've also tried hard coding the value in that command in case that had anything to do with it.  I've tried defining this as an environmental variable too (just in case)...

Nothing works.  Yet, I've seen piles of examples where this syntax seems to be valid.  What am doing wrong?  Could there be a character escape complication?

Comment: Is the variable part of the `.qmake.conf` file? the parameters are only applied to the pro file, and not the qmake config.  It's possible you need to pass the correct qmake spec via the `--spec` parameter. Check the `mkspecs` directory to find the correct one, or create your own one. This might work.

Comment: Thanks, Felix.  I'll take a look at the --spec parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the shell already interpreted the ${} inside your string as a form of variable substitution.
Since you did not define the variable CROSS_COMPILE in the shell, it had no value and what qmake got were actually the 2 arguments between quotes "qt.pro" and "CROSS_COMPILE=", meaning that you have actually made qmake set CROSS_COMPILE to an empty value.
What you should try is:

```
qmake qt.pro "CROSS_COMPILE=\${CROSS_COMPILE}"
```

Note the backslash before the dollar sign, which escapes it to prevent it from having a special meaning to the shell and enables it to get passed on literally to qmake.

This question has also been already asked on Stackoverflow:

[Define a string in qmake command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308363/define-a-string-in-qmake-command-line)

More on the variable substitution of Bash:

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

EDIT:

Example:
I just tried myself with a fresh project file with the following contents:

SOME_OTHER_VAR=$${SOME_VAR}_something 
message($${SOME_OTHER_VAR})

and doing

```
SOME_VAR=value
qmake qmake_variables.pro "SOME_VAR=${SOME_VAR}"
```

does work for me, printing:

```
Project MESSAGE: value_something
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had defined / exported the CROSS_COMPILE variable in the shell though.  I just omitted that detail from my post.

Comment: I just edited the post. I wanted to put it in a comment first, but the formatting for comments is terrible.
EDIT: Have you verified that the value of CROSS_COMPILE is indeed what  you wanted it to be immediately before running qmake in the script?
Or maybe the project file is such that a makefile will overwrite the user defined value of CROSS_COMPILE somewhere?

Comment: Hmm.  Well, at least it works like it's supposed to some of the time.  My problem must have been contextual some how.  This was all being triggered by multiple nesting of scripts.  Those layers might have been part of the problem.  Fortunately, I threw out the process I was trying to run, and everything worked when executed on a lower level.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best answer, but I "solved" the problem by adding this to my qmake.conf:

```
CROSS_COMPILE=$$(CROSS_COMPILE)
```

That defined the variable in qmake by getting it from an environmental variable I set in my calling bash script.